# R: failed to compile text_files/figure-latex/fig1-1.tikz to PDF

Tags: r, knitr, figure

After I updated my R to version 3.42 and miktex to version 2.9, I couldn't knit my file with figures to pdf. Could anyone help?

```
Error: failed to compile text_files/figure-latex/fig1-1.tikz to PDF
In addition: Warning message:
running command 

`'"C:\Users\our\AppData\Local\Programs\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe" 
"fig1-1.tikz"' had status 1
```

Comment: It is clearly something wrong with your configuration, and therefore it would help to know what code you are running. Can you provide an example which we would be able to reproduce?

Comment: I would recommend reading this. It gives some tips on asking a questions in a way that makes it easy for people to provide help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ```{r fig1,fig.width=8,fig.height=4,echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,fig.cap="10-day SP 500 returns (2007-2016)"}
plot(ret[1:t],type = "l" , xlab = " " , ylab = "Return" , main = "10-day SP 500 returns (2007-2016)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comment. For example, I just include one figure in the code. Then I knit it with
rmarkdown::render("text.Rmd")

It turns out to be the error above. When I use R in Mac OS, there is no error.

Figure code:

`{r fig1,fig.width=8,fig.height=4,echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,fig.cap="10-day SP 500 returns (2007-2016)"}
plot(ret[1:t],type = "l" , xlab = " " , ylab = "Return" , main = "10-day SP 500 returns (2007-2016)")`